# is there any way to animate images or make all kinds of animations in react -native

Tags: animation, react-native

I have been working on a project in which needs a lot of animations to be done like riding a cycle, movement  of eyes of a smiley or a person in picture. I don't really get this with the usual react-native animation. Is there any other way to get this done?

Answer (score 4):

They could definitely be done through the Animated API of react native but if you aren't too familiar with it, it might become a little too much. Another alternative would be to use Adobe After Effects to design your animations and then import them into your react native project using the Lottie package for react native.

https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native

Comment: so there is a way to select coordinate points on screen in react native and move it?

Comment: well the best answer to that is, yes it is somewhat possible. Basically lets take riding a cycle for example, it would be possible to animate wheels turning around by using the animated api to animate a number from 0 to 360 over time and then using that number as the rotation for your wheel(could be a view or an image). But again like i said this would involve a bunch of stuff which you may be unwilling to do ( including writing a bunch of code for simply rotating and moving your images around.) and while personally I love the Animated API i do understand that its also frustrating.

Comment: yes i did the wheel rotation but when it comes to rotating two wheels and drawing  a cycle and move it along, gets really complicated.by the way thanks !